# How to use jq for parsing JSON as env vars

Tags: jq

I have the following json structure

```
[{"name":"SQS_URL","value":"xyz"}]
```

I would like to convert it to this structure

```
SQS_URL=XZY
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like:

```
$ echo '[{"name":"SQS_URL","value":"xyz"},{"name":"foo","value":"bar"}]' | jq -r '.[] | "\(.name)=\(.value)"'
SQS_URL=xyz
foo=bar
```

The `.[]` part gets you the elements of the array, and the `"\(.name)=\(.value)"` part gets you the `name=value` output, where `name` and `value` are the field names of the structure.

Answer (score 3):

To ensure that you get the data appropriately quoted for the shell:

```bash
$ jq -r 'map("\(.name)=\(.value|@sh)")[]' file
SQS_URL='xyz'
```

The `@sh` operator handles shell quoting.

Would you also want to upper-case the value (as shown in the question):

```bash
$ jq -r 'map("\(.name)=\(.value|ascii_upcase|@sh)")[]' file
SQS_URL='XYZ'
```

You can then `eval` the output if you trust that the data provided is safe (we assume that the `name` is a valid variable name and that `value` is a scalar):

```bash
$ unset -v SQS_URL
$ eval "$( jq -r 'map("\(.name)=\(.value|ascii_upcase|@sh)")[]' file )"
$ printf '%s\n' "$SQS_URL"
XYZ
```

This would also support a longer array of names and values (here, I've additionally used `name` strings that cause assignments to be done to the elements of an array, for the ease of testing):

```bash
$ cat file
[
   { "name": "a[0]", "value": "xyz0" },
   { "name": "a[1]", "value": "This contains\na newline" },
   { "name": "a[2]", "value": "hello 'world'" }
]
```

```bash
$ jq -r 'map("\(.name)=\(.value|ascii_upcase|@sh)")[]' file
a[0]='XYZ0'
a[1]='THIS CONTAINS
A NEWLINE'
a[2]='HELLO '\''WORLD'\'''
```

```bash
$ unset -v a
$ eval "$( jq -r 'map("\(.name)=\(.value|ascii_upcase|@sh)")[]' file )"
$ printf '<<%s>>\n' "${a[@]}"
<<XYZ0>>
<<THIS CONTAINS
A NEWLINE>>
<<HELLO 'WORLD'>>
```

If you actually want *environment* variables, then we need to `export` them.  I would do that with another `jq` expression entirely:

```bash
jq -r 'map(["export", "\(.name)=\(.value|ascii_upcase)"]|@sh)[]' file
```

This creates output like

```bash
'export' 'a=XYZ0'
'export' 'b=THIS CONTAINS
A NEWLINE'
'export' 'c=HELLO '\''WORLD'\'''
```

... which, if evaluated, would correctly assign and export the three environment variables `a`, `b` and `c` (the fact that the keyword `export` is quoted does not really matter).